# how read configuration adapter from database in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Thanks for attention
i using `Spring Integration` in my project , i want to read configuration such as auto-startup,remote-directory,etc from database, how do it ?
my code as below:

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="my-inbound-channel-adapter"
                                     channel="ready-to-process-inbound-tmp-mover"
                                     session-factory="ftp-Session"
                                     auto-create-local-directory="..... read from db......"
                                     delete-remote-files="..... read from db......"
                                     auto-startup="..... read from db......"
                                     filename-regex="..... read from db......"
                                     remote-directory="..... read from db......"
                                     remote-file-separator="/"
                                     local-filename-generator-expression="...stuff code..."
                                     temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
                                     local-directory="..... read from db......">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="..... read from db......" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SpEL` to call a method in a bean - `#{myConfigBean.autoStartupSetting}` will call `getAutoStartupSetting()`.

Or have your method return a map: `public Map<?, ?> getSettings()`.

Then `#{myConfigBean.settings['autoStartup']}`.

Comment: thanks @Gary for fast response, how to i can refresh this configuration during runtime?